# Izpack installer - I want to modify target path

Tags: java, izpack

I used [Izpack](http://izpack.org/) to create an installer. The target path the user will choose will be used to replace placeholders in windows `.bat` files which works fine until the user chooses a path with spaces like `c:\Program Files\plapla`, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put double quotes around the paths that include placeholders in the `.bat` files

```
"${THEPATH}\example.txt"
```

This should then work in all cases, both when the path contains spaces and when it doesn't.